# Trocar o nome de um elemento em uma JList

Tags: java, swing, lista

Saudações, amigos.

Estou com um problema em Java.

[image: Na foto: O cadastro a ser realizado]

Estou tentando adicionar um elemento do tipo "Ocorrência" numa JList. Este elemento possui 4 elementos dentro do mesmo, que preciso manter. Até aí tudo bem.

Porém, o problema aparece quando eu adiciono o dito elemento a lista

[image: O problema]

A lista apresenta este nome no elemento. Por quê? Gostaria que, no lugar deste nome, aparecesse o nome da ocorrência.

Eis o código da ocorrência:

```
 @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //dispose();
            Ocorrencia ocorrencia = new Ocorrencia();
            ocorrencia.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            ocorrencia.setVisible(true);
            ocorrenciasAtivas.modeloOcorrencias.addElement(ocorrencia);

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa implementar `toString()` na sua classe `Ocorrencia`.

Esse método deve retornar uma versão legível dos dados do seu objeto como `String`. Como você não fez isso, a `JList` usou a implementação padrão, que é essa `String` feia que você está vendo.

Comment: Excelente resposta. Rápida e prática. Substituí o método toString da classe retornando a String de nome. Agradeço, Pablo!